# Should I rely on TTL (time to live) when using scan in HBase or should I use timestamp as part of the key

Tags: hbase

I'm using TTL for a project I'm involved in.
I understand that feature wise, when I'm performing a scan, I will not get the expired data back.
I was just wondering what is the performance effect of the expired data (between major compactions). 
We have TTL of 10 minutes and a lot of data that is gathered (and expired) so I was wondering if using TTL is the correct approach or maybe using a timestamp as part of the key and doing a scan that doesn't actually include the expired range.

Comment: using TS might lead you to RS hotspotting

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HBase filter with your scan to filter out the expired rows on the HBase server side. From memory, I don't remember whether cell timestamps are something you can use as part of a filter expression.

- If they are, you can just use them directly with whatever filter does that (I think there may not be one).
- If not, you can add a timestamp column to your column family and then use a [ValueFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ValueFilter.html) to filter out rows whose timestamps are less than or equal to a threshold timestamp. This option stores a redundant timestamp, but that would be an okay trade off if it allows you to use a filter.

One thing you definitely shouldn't choose is to use a row key that looks like `"{timestamp}{other data}"`.  That will make your HBase table work like an enormous queue, which will kill performance.

Comment: The question is what is better. Is the performance of using TTL better than using any of the other filters?

Comment: Try out each method and profile performance. You're going to be using TTL regardless.  The question is simply whether you filter the HBase cell timestamps or some cell contents that happen to be timestamps that you manually insert.